# WordPress search - Do nothing if no search string has been entered

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following snippet of code:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>/">
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" id="t" value="&gt;" class="searchsubmit">
</form>
```

Unfortunately if no search string is entered, and the submit button is pressed or Enter is hit, then it takes you off to an undesired page.

For me this is the blog page as I can see the 'blog' class in the body.

How can I prevent the search from triggering until a string is entered?

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Comment: will the HTML5 `required` attribute work for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One -  You can use the HTML5 `required` attribute in your input tag

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" required/>
```

It's not fully supported in all browsers though and you can check that here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Browser_compatibility

Two - Bind a submit handler to your form and check before submitting - that way it handles the button click plus enter key press in the form

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(){
    if($('#s').val() == ''){
        return false;
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#searchform').submit(function(e){
    if($('#s').val() == ''){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yQY62/)

Answer (score 2):

You can either block the form with jQuery so it does not submit if empty, as Pavlo suggests, which can still be worked-around by typing `?s=` in the address bar ...

Or Put this on your `functions.php`. It will redirect empty search submissions to homepage again:

```
function search_redirect($query) {
   if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) 
      if ($query->is_search) {
          wp_redirect( home_url() ); exit;
      }
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_redirect');
```

Comment: Yes I would prefer nothing at all to happen.  I don't particularly think it is good usability to send a user to the home page if they have not entered a string in the search although this is more desirable than taking them to the blog page.

Comment: Use jQuery then and use this solution as a backup.

You can also redirect the the current location in the site too, so they don't see the difference.

Comment: is_search ? You mean is_search() ?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you were looking for?

```
$('#t').click(function(){
  if($('#s').val() == ''){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, although this isn't currently working.  Still takes me off to the blog page.

Comment: Sorry, missing a closing parenthesis in my code.  This works nicely and I will use in conjunction with Banago's solution.  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: it's always best to use bind to the form's submit handler and not the click handler of the submit button - if someone hit's enter inside the form - it will trigger the submit handler not the click - which will cause the form to still submit

Comment: ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ - is absolutely correct. Johnny, you should better to use his answer in you code instead of mine.

Comment: I do agree having just had a read up however your solution that I have accepted is not causing the form to submit upon Enter either.